# Passing JSON through a GraphQl mutation

Tags: json, graphql

I have form data coming from the front end that gets passed through graphql to my postgreql database. In an effort to avoid passing a long list of strings through graphql i wanted to use json. After exhausting my google and DOC options I am humbly asking for help understanding how this is done. In the end if i can just get a valid json object into my AddForm resolver id be happy. Thanks in advance to your time.

**The Mutation looks like this**

```
mutation AddForm ($formHeader: String!, $formBody: String!, $formComments: String!) {
  addForm(formHeader: $formHeader, formBody: $formBody, formComments: $formComments)  {
    id
   formHeader
   formBody
   formComments
  }
}
```

**The variables look like this (simplified for example purposes)**

$formHeader

```
{
    "name": "graylagx",
    "date": "today",
    "equipment": "water",
}
```

$formBody

```
{
    "InternalCheckList": {
        "Check1": "yes",
        "Check2": "N/A",
     },
     "ExternalCheckList": {
         "Check1": "yes",
         "Check2": "yes",
      }
}
```

$formComments

```
"This is a very long comment string"
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in the graphql resolver for `addForm` mutation will have all the input variables as a JSON object with keys `formHeader`, `formBody`, and `formComments` and values as defined by the inputs in your schema